# How to check whether an object key exists or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am getting an object from backend and that object has several keys and values. According to the database data sometimes some of the keys won't be available. So I have used ternary operator for it but still, it is not working.

```
 `
  <tr>
     <td>
         ${(df[temp].image.status)?df[temp].image.status:'Not Assigned'}
     </td>
  </tr>
  `
```

Expected result:
Whether an "image" key is there or not there shouldn't be any error.
Either it should be some status or 'Not Assigned';

Current result:
TypeError: df[temp].image is undefined

Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: One is `image.status` and the other says `imagestatus`. The first one probably has an extra `.`

Comment: Check wether `df[temp].image` exists at first.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking on already `undefined` value. First you need to verify that `image` exists and then you can access its fields.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        ${(df[temp].image && df[temp].image.status) ? (df[temp].image.status) : 'Not Assigned'}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so we cant directly check for df[temp].image.status?

Comment: @lealceldeiro good point, edited answer to include check also for status field

Comment: @swetasharma no, you cannot, whenever you try to access `status`, you need to have `image` object present already

Comment: you don't need the ternary here `df[temp].image && df[temp].image.status || 'Not Assigned' ` will also work.